# Показать информацию о таблицах

Tags: postgresql

Подскажите пожалуйста какой командой можно показать в теримнал инфу о таблице: ее связи, constraint-ы, references, primary key-и, типы, уникальные значения  и прочую служебную инфу.
Моих способностей к гуглению хватило на

```
SELECT column_name, column_default, data_type 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name = 'table_name';
```

и на более детальное [описание](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/183/information-schema-columns/) что можно найти в `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Но там не вижу нужной мне инфы, которую я перечислил выше, вернее вижу не только лишь всю инфу, мало какую инфу вижу))Помогите пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, Вы имеете в виду информацию о конкретной таблице? Её можно вывести с помощью команд [`EXPLAIN/DESCRIBE имя_таблицы`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) (обе взаимозаменяемы) и [`SHOW COLUMNS FROM имя_таблицы`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-columns.html), как-то так:

```sql
mysql> DESCRIBE City;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name       | char(35) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Country    | char(3)  | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| District   | char(20) | YES  | MUL |         |                |
| Population | int(11)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Если же дело касается PostgreSQL (как у автора вопроса), то достаточно применить команду `\d имя_таблицы` (более подробно можно почитать [здесь](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-describe-table/)). Вывод при этом будет выглядеть примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Видимо для postgresql эта команда не работает)

Comment: Благодаря вашему овтету получилось нагуглить команду \d для postgresql. Благодарен бемерно)

Comment: @umd пожалуйста. Кстати, добавил способ для Вашей системы в свой ответ, если интересно. Если хотите, можете пометить мой ответ верным через галочку (или Ваш собственный)

Comment: Увидел. Помечу ваш, так как он более полный и поможет тем кто не с postgres работает и тем кто с postgres)

Answer (score 0):

Команда `\d table_name` дает нужную инфу)